# How to use batch file to give inputs for a jar file in every step automatically?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I am using a prepared jar file to process 1000 HTML files. As the number of files is big, I want to do this process automatically. The name of HTML files that I want to read are `result_1` to `result_1000` and all theses HTML files are in a folder called `Results`. I want to process all these result files in a **FOR** loop.

This jar file prompts the user for the working directory. After entering the working directory, it prompts for the file name. After entering the file name, it prompts about the processing method.

I am using this part of code to process the results. But it doesn't work fine. I don't have any idea of this jar file and how it works. I wrote this part of code to try if it processes one result file correctly, but it doesn't do anything. It just runs the java file without passing the inputs.

I am thinking that after running the jar file by this batch file it gives the control to the jar file and then can't get the inputs from the batch file.

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Could you please help me what can I do for processing these files.

```
@echo off
set "workingdirectory=C:\Results"
set "filename=result_1.html"
set "processingmethod=methodD"
cd C:\JavaFolder
java -jar myjavacode.jar "%workingdirectory% %filename% %processingmethod%
```

Comment: From what I understood on reading task description is that the Java application expects the directory, file name and method from standard input stream __STDIN__ and not as parameters on starting it. In this case you would need to create dynamically a text file with first line containing the directory, second line the file name and third line the method and redirect this file with `<` via __STDIN__ to the Java application. See the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: @Mofi I tried this it just can read the and I give the input from text file it just can read the working directory but not the rest of txt file

Comment: Well, if an application is written for interacting with a human user and not for a scripted use, you definitely have a real problem to use it scripted. Modify the Java application to accept the 3 strings as parameters from command line if this is possible. Contact the author of the Java application if that is necessary because you can't modify the Java code.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
cd C:\JavaFolder
for /l %%k in (1, 1000, 1) do java -jar myjavacode.jar C:\Results result_%k.html methodD
```

This will start and stop the JVM 1000 times, not really good. I suggest you try to invoke the main method programmatically, unless that main method exit with `System.exit()` (or equivalent) and will install its own `SecurityManager`.